# How to select positive square root expression in SymPy solve?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm calculating an expression for a variable (p2) in terms of other variables (q1,q2,p1) by solving an expression (hamiltonian=energy). The solve method returns two solutions (positive and negative) corresponding to the same square root. Below is the sample code:

```
state_symbols = ['q1', 'q2','p1','p2']
sympy_symbols = sp.symbols([tuple(state_symbols)])

hamiltonian = "(q1**2+q2**2+p1**2+p2**2)/(2)+ (q1**2*q2 - (q2**3)/(3))"
sys_fn = sp.sympify(sys_hamiltonian, evaluate=False)

sym_energy = sp.Symbol('energy')

expr_p2 = sp.solve(
            sys_fn - sym_energy, sympy_symbols[0][-1])
```

Now this `expr_p2` is a list of two solutions one of which is positive square root. How do I assert that the one I pick is always a positive square?

Comment: If you set your symbol as `positive=True` when you create it, `solve` will filter the solutions automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest sure way is to write `a,b=expr_p2; Piecewise((a, Gt(a, b)), (b, True))`. When symbols are involved SymPy should be canonical but the canonical answer may not place the positive answer 2nd:

```
>>> solve(a*x**2+b*x+c,x)
[(-b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
>>> solve(-a*x**2+b*x+c,x)
[(b - sqrt(4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), (b + sqrt(4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
```

In the former, the greater root is first if `a` is positive while in the latter it is second if `a` is positive.

Comment: Thanks! In my case `b=0` and I'm getting `expr_p2 = [-sqrt(....),+sqrt(...)]` which means I have to select the second one. This seems to contradict your criteria.

Comment: sorry...I meant to put `b` instead of 0 in the `Gt`. I updated to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
pos_soln = max(expr_p2)
```

This is direct and simple.

Comment: Well, in this case it gives: `TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational`.

Comment: Agree with @JohanC, it throws the same error for me as well.

Comment: You specified that `expr_p2` is a list of 2 values.  This works on a list or tuple, as well as several other sequences.